# How to map oldest item from association

Tags: hibernate

Say I have 1k entities to load. Each of them has association with a lot of associated entities. Each entity has timestamp. I'd like to get top entity and ONE associated entity, the most recent one.

Lazy loading has to be in place, since I don't want (always, especially in this case) list of all associated entities. It's pointless to fetch all entities to get just one.

I can fetch top entities, then construct list of their PK, and issue 1 sql statement to find all associated entities having one of given FK, and most recent timestamp and then manually pair them to previously fetch entities. That's easy.

But I'd like to ask if there is an easier way using some hibernate mapping.

Comment: You might be able to map this using Hibernate formula, but the data would not remain consistent in case an associated entity is created with the most recent timestamp. Using an sql/hql query might be the easiest route here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't do that in entities as the query would have to be executed every time you fetch that entity. You should use a custom query for this instead, something like the following:

```
select e, sub
from Entity e
left join e.subs sub
on sub.timestamp = (select min(timestamp) from e.subs s)
```

If this doesn't work because the timestamp is not unique, you'd have to filter out duplicates manually or make use [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage) which has builtin support for this.

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(Entity.class)
public interface EntityDto {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    String getName();
    @Limit(limit = "1", order = "timestamp ASC")
    @Mapping("subs")
    SubDto getOldest();

    @EntityView(Sub.class)
    interface SubDto {
        @IdMapping
        Long getId();
        String getName();
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`EntityDto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, EntityDto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features